# Nextjs getServerSideProps not passing updated props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've the challenge that in a nextjs page the `getServerSideProps` is not passing the updated props.

My page structure is as follows

```bash
|-pages
 |-notifications
  |-emails
   |-index.tsx
   |-activate.tsx
```

In the page `pages/notifications/emails/index.tsx` the `getServerSideProps` fecthes all emails related to a user from an API and populates the props for the page as follows:

```js
type Props = {
  emails: Array<RecordEmail>;
  error?: string;
};

const Notifications = ({ emails: initialEmails, error }: Props) => {
  const [emails, setEmails] = useState<Array<RecordEmail>>(initialEmails);
  return (
   <div className="mt-4 flex flex-col space-y-2">
          <pre className="bg-gray-100 p-2 font-gtpressuratibold text-xs">
            <code>{JSON.stringify(emails, undefined, 2)}</code>
          </pre>
          <pre className="bg-gray-100 p-2 font-gtpressuratibold text-xs">
            <code>{JSON.stringify(initialEmails, undefined, 2)}</code>
          </pre>
        </div>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Props> = async (
  context
) => {
  context.res.setHeader(
    "Cache-Control",
    "private, s-maxage=1, stale-while-revalidate=1"
  );
  const session = await unstable_getServerSession(
    context.req,
    context.res,
    authOptions
  );

  try {
    const result = await FETCHDATA(with session token)
    
    const emails: Array<RecordEmail> = [];

    result.items.forEach((a) => {
      if (typeof a["email"] !== "undefined") {
        const r: RecordEmail = {
          id: a.id,
          email: a["email"],
          primary: a["primary"],
          valid: a["valid"],
        };
        emails.push(r);
      }
    });
    console.log("Emails getServerSideProps - emails: ", emails);
    return {
      props: {
        emails: [...emails],
      },
    };
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.error(err);
    return {
      props: {
        emails: [],
        error: (err as Error).message,
      },
    };
  }
};

export default Notifications;
```

On the page `pages/notifications/emails/activate.tsx` the user enters an activation code to activate the email. After submitting the code the email is activated. This works as seen in the DB and the API. By clicking a `<Link>` the user navigates to the page `pages/notifications/emails/index.tsx` to see all emails.

By navigating to the page `pages/notifications/emails/index.tsx` the `getServerSideProps` requests the new data correctly. The `console.log("Emails getServerSideProps - emails: ", emails);` logs the updated data. But the page shows still the old data (the data before submitting the activation code).

Does anyone know why the updates props are not correctly passed to the page?

Additional question: On the page `pages/notifications/emails/activate.tsx` I'm not using `getServerSideProps`. But, by navigating this page (either via `<Link>` or complete new refresh) the `getServerSideProps` from the page `pages/notifications/emails/index.tsx` is called. Is this by design?

Thanks for your help!

Update: After refreshing the page completely or navigating by `<Link>` to another page and then back passes the data correctly.

Comment: If you log `initialEmails` to the console inside `Notifications`, do you see the updated value when you navigate to that page?

Comment: Hi, I've deleted the complete git directory, cloned the repository again, build the nextjs-application new and started the app in production mode. Now, I can't reproduce this issue anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

When your `initialEmails` change your state won't change

```
const [emails, setEmails] = useState<Array<RecordEmail>>(initialEmails);
```

### Solution

Remove the state. Props shouldn't be stored inside a state.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I'm mutating the state `emails` on the client side. That's why I'm setting the initial state. However, the `initialEmails` doesn't event change in the render.